# 1992 Mitsubishi 3000GT SL: No power and engine won't go above 2K RPM

Tags: automatic-transmission, power, rpm

I bought an automatic 1992 Mitsubishi 3000GT SL 2 days ago. I got it cheap knowing it would have problems, and that's why I'm here.

When I put it in drive and slam on the gas the car just simply moves forward really slowly, and the engine won't go above 2,000 rpm. When I took it home it was overheating so I checked the coolant level and put some in; now it's ok with no leaks.

I heard it might be the cat? Would it fix it if I took it off without damaging the sensor? I don't care if it ridiculously loud. I just want the car to get its power back.

Also when I put the car into low gear and drive and shift up it seems like its not even working. It seems like its just stuck in one gear. It does accelerate, just really really slowly.

Comment: I would give you 10:1 the catalytic converter is plugged. There have been a plethora of other questions of the same-same, but for the life of me I cannot find one to flag your question with.

Comment: so if i would take it off would that solve it maybe?

Comment: nope wasn't the cat...

Comment: Are you getting any pinging/knocking? Can you rev the engine up when it's in neutral?

Comment: Did you pull the codes?

Comment: Voting to close. Broad range of problems, and OP stopped responding to comments.